# How to retrieve properties from ASP.NET Membership, Profile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-authorization

In web.config i defined the property:

```
<profile>
  <properties>
    <add name ="Creator" type ="System.String"/>        
  </properties>
</profile>
```

I can set values to this property, like

```
 HttpContext.Profile.SetPropertyValue("Creator", Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString());
```

But how can I get the value, based on MembershipUser? If i iterate through MembershipUserCollection in my view, how can I display my property `Creator`?

```
 @foreach (MembershipUser user in (ViewData["Users"] as MembershipUserCollection))
 {
    //how to get @user Creator?
 }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Profile properties are not set on the MembershipUser object. Instead, for an authenticated user, you can simply use the "Profile" property directly in your code:

```
Profile.Creator
```